# Is possible to view both Graphic layout and layout.xml in the same time?

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm new to Android development and for me, a good way to learn how the Graphic layout and xml relate to each other is by trying an xml attribute and see the changes in the Graphic UI. Is there a way to see both side by side in the same time and not have to switch from one to another?
The picture show what I want to achieve.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [IntelliJ Idea](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/). It's an IDE that has this feature.

**Edit:** I'm not sure I understood your question well, but what I got was that you want to make changes and see them update automatically. This feature IS present in Idea:
[image: The preview pane does what you need]

Comment: I don't want to change IDE. Idea does not provide side by side design and xml. only design and properties, just like eclipse

Comment: OK...I see now. But I want to stay with Eclipse because the community is bigger (at the moment). Maybe in the future I will try IntelliJ Idea. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Here is a better answer.

1. Open Layout
2. Windows -> New Editor
3. Set one window to Graphical, another window to xml

[Eclipse IDE - Android Graphical Layout and XML Layout Side by Side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13169743/eclipse-ide-android-graphical-layout-and-xml-layout-side-by-side)

Answer (score 2):

In the mean time I've found a different and more elegant way of doing this split (still in Eclipse R 4.4.0 + ADT 23.0.3.1327240):

1. Open Layout XML file.
2. Window > Editor > Toggle Split Editor (Vertical)
3. Select Graphical Layout in the pane to the right.

The clever thing about this approach is that the two split panes are retained within the editor tab.

Answer (score 1):

Currently Both graphical and xml editor in same window is not there in Eclipse.

Update your Android SDK Tools to Revision 21

The update includes new tools and capabilities that can help you work more efficiently as you create applications. Tools such as a new multi-config editor, and new Lint rules will help you..

Ref here:[enter link description here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.br/2012/11/android-sdk-tools-revision-21.html)

**Multi-config editor**
A new multi-configuration editor allows you to develop and prototype your UI across various orientations, screen sizes and locales. For example, while editing your layout in portrait mode, you can see if your edits aren't visible in the shorter landscape orientation.
[image]

Comment: I like the way Multi-config editor looks like. I'm updating to version 21 of Android SDK right now. Thank you

Comment: @SynapseOne ya even more useful in creating emulator for exact devices.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it in Eclipse Luna R 4.4.0 + ADT 23.0.3.1327240:

1. Open Layout XML file.
2. Window -> Editor Clone
3. Drag the new editor tab and place it next to the current editor window.
4. Set one editor window to Graphical Layout and the other to XML.

I can recommend an Eclipse setup with three windows next to each other:

1. Package Explorer, usually collapsed) | 2. XML | 3. Graphical with its Outline Structure panel open.

Caveats:

1. Changes made in XML do not automatically get reflected in the graphical window; you need to perform some action here, a click will suffice.
2. Selecting a new XML file in the Package Explorer will only open it in one (e.g. the XML) editor window, not both; you will need to select the other (e.g. Graphical) editor window and open the file in here too.  Thankfully both windows have tabs of recently opened files, so this isn't *that* much of a hassle.
3. The usual Outline Window (Window > Show View > Outline) links with the currently selected editor; if you don't show the same file in both the Graphical and XML editor window, things may get confusing.